# How to redirect visitor to another page after certain time in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, timeout

What are some hidden tricks of PHP in putting timeout on the page and redirect it to another page?

Comment: This question helps! Don't vote it down!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) on the server-side then redirect to another page with [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Or you can send an HTML page with `<meta>` tag that specifies redirect location and delay time.

**Using sleep and header**

```
<?php
sleep(2);
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

**Using `<meta>` tag**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://www.example.com/">
```

Comment: ```header("refresh: 5; http://www.example.com/");```